# associativity of smash product up to homotopy equivalence

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

For two based topological spaces $(X,x_0)$ and $(Y,y_0)$, the smash product $X\wedge Y$ is the quotient $(X\times Y)/(X\vee Y)$, where $X\vee Y$ is the subspace $(X\times\{y_0\})\cup(\{x_0\}\times Y)$.

On the category of based topological spaces, the smash product does not associate. Counterexamples are not super easy to come by and prove, but the most well-known can be found [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/196084/counterexample-for-associativity-of-smash-product).

Now among spaces which are either locally compact and Hausdorff, or which are compactly generated, the smash product **is associative**. In particular, this covers all CW complexes and manifolds, which is nice. In addition, via CW approximations, we can at least see that

$$\pi_n((X\wedge Y)\wedge Z)\cong \pi_n(X\wedge(Y\wedge Z))$$

for all $n$. However, I don't see how to upgrade this to even a weak homotopy equivalence in general. My question is the following.

> For any pointed topological spaces $X,Y,Z$, is $X\wedge(Y\wedge Z)$ homotopy equivalent to $(X\wedge Y)\wedge Z$?

Comment: How does the argument by CW approximations go? Does smashing commute with CW approximations?

Comment: That's a good point; I assumed so but I can't actually think of a proof right now.

Comment: It is true if each of $X,Y,Z$ is nondegenerately based (nbd). For a space $A$ write $A'=A\cup_\ast I$ as the result of attaching a whisker at the basepoint. If $A$ is ndb then the canonical map $A'\rightarrow A$ is a homotopy equivalence. Now replace $X,Y,Z$ with their primed counterparts and work with the span $(X'\wedge Y')\wedge Z'\leftarrow X'\wedge  Y'\wedge Z'\rightarrow(X'\wedge Y')\wedge Z'$, where the middle space is the obvious quotient, showing that each map is a pointed homotopy equivalence. The details aren't difficult but are annoying to write down (and I'm at work right now).

Comment: I have no proof/counterexample in the case in which one of the spaces has a degenerate basepoint.